# Improving the efficiency of a query that uses COUNT, MIN and MAX

Tags: php, mysql

*I recently posted about what essentially boils down to the same issue but using a different database technology (meaning the solution found - which involved using ROW_NUMBER() - is not applicable here).*

Lets say I have a table in a MySQL database called "Customers". I also have a table called "Orders", each of which contains a "CustomerID". What I want to do, is to generate a summary for each "Customer" of how many orders they have made, as well as when their first and last "Order" took place.

The query I have been using for this is as follows:

```
SELECT
    Customer.CustomerID,
    Customer.Name,
    COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS Orders,
    MIN(Order.Timestamp) AS OldestOrder,
    MAX(Orders.Timestamp) AS NewestOrder
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customerts ON Orders.OrderID = Customers.CustomerID
GROUP BY Orders.CustomerID
```

This query gets exactly what I want, but on a database containing several hundred thousand orders, it can take 2-3 seconds to execute.

By adding an index to the "Orders" table that includes "CustomerID" and "Timestamp", this time is brought down to around 1 second or less, but this is still unacceptable. The list of customers this query will be executed for is usually relatively small, so a loop through each customer that performs individual queries to obtain the data is a quicker option, but this is much more messy.

Are there further index opportunities I'm not seeing, or does this query need to function in a totally different way? If I had MSSQL's ROW_NUMBER() functionality at my disposal this query could work incredibly quickly...

Thanks in advance :)!

EDIT #1: EXPLAIN SELECT shows:

```
id  select_type  table      type       possible_keys  key           key_len  ref                   rows  Extra
1   SIMPLE       Customers  ALL        PRIMARY        NULL          NULL     NULL                  10    Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE       Orders     ref        CustomerID_2   CustomerID_2  4        Customers.CustomerID  4038  Using where
```

Comment: Add `Customer.Name` to the `group by` clause and then use `explain select ...` to get the execution plan

Comment: As a minimum, questions about query performance always require CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables and an EXPLAIN. Also, it appears as if you're asking two different things, because I can't see what benefit MSSQL's ROW_NUMBER option would afford.

Comment: @juergend I have added an explain as best I can.

Comment: @Strawberry This query is a simplified version of the real one, I don't have any CREATEs for the real data I'm afraid as the context (Customers and Orders) is totally different. I was hoping to attack this on a higher level

Comment: I can only deal with more earthly matters unfortunately.

Comment: The answer was ultimately found by adjusting the existing index (see my answer). Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appear the answer was right in front of me! Replacing the index I mentioned in the OP which included "CustomerID" and "Timestamp" with one that also included "OrderID" brought the query down to around 0.07 seconds! This was then further reduced by roughly 50% by using the "Customers" table as the focal point, as outlined in Jignesh Patel's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    Customers.CustomerID,
    Customers.Name,
    COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS Orders,
    MIN(Orders.Timestamp) AS OldestOrder,
    MAX(Orders.Timestamp) AS NewestOrder
FROM Customers  
INNER JOIN Orders ON Orders.CustomerID= Customers.CustomerID
GROUP BY Customers.CustomerID
```

Comment: Could you add some clarification insteead of just posting the code ?

Comment: This is an interesting take on solving the problem! It is indeed quicker than the original query, but is sadly still way too slow. In addition, I'm hoping to solve the issue at a higher level so it can be broadly applied across multiple queries, I'm not sure a solution this specific really does it.

Comment: how much time it is taking ? is index created on CustomerID field in both the table ?

Comment: Around .5 seconds with an index in both

Comment: You can use technique called materialized view, specific tool mysql don't have. But idea is to create table, ant recalculate data on every update, if you don't have much update/insert operations. Or refresh data by interval, if it acceptable by your requirements.

Comment: Upvoted as your answer provided a further reduction. The answer however was ultimately found by adjusting the existing index (see my answer). Thank you for your help!